# jquery datepicker onSelect won't call custom function in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a datepicker initialized such as:

`$("#startDate").datepicker({
    onSelect: dateChanged
});`

This works in conjunction with the input:

`<input type="text" id="startDate" value="" class="dateField"/>`

that is in a table for a search over a jquery dataTable.

This works great in chrome, but fails to work in IE. My goal is to have today's data populate the `dataTable` then when the start date changes to a previous date the `onSelect` should call the `dateChanged` function. The `dateChanged` function is responsible for querying the database again but with an earlier date.

In IE what happens is that when you select the text box for the date the calendar come up(good). When you select the desired date the calendar does not go away.

I have had a test function call with no problems. The difference is that the test function just has an alert and the `dateChanged` function has variables initialized and query calls. It seems to work fine until I create a variable of any sort.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

**UPDATE**

Here is a little more of the function I am trying to call:

```
function dateChanged(){  
        var StartTime = startDate.value;  
    var EndTime = endDate.value;  
    alert("hello");  
    var cmecProx2 = new cmec();  
...  
}
```

Most of the code I have I cannot share due to it being for a company I work for but from the code above I am not getting to the alert statement.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code and if possible, create a jsFiddle?

Comment: How do you know that you're getting into the function at all? What are startDate and endDate?

Comment: startDate and endDate are input fields. I know am because previously I had alert statements before the var declarations. Like I said it works in chrome great but not IE and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers don't fire events in a timely fashion. So what works well in FF/Chrome may not work at all in IE. I've had good success in these situations by wrapping the event code in a timeout.

```
$("#startDate").datepicker({ onSelect: function(){setTimeout(dateChanged, 500);} });
```

This will delay the firing of `dateChanged()` by half a second, and--if timing is the problem--would give IE enough time to realize the `onSelect` event has fired.

Comment: This seems strange to me. The way I have this page set up is that the script tag is inside the body tag. There is a table being populated inside a `$(documnet).ready` call and everything else including the datepicker is outside of that in their own functions. I updated my code to your suggestion and now on page load it fires the dateChanged function. Is this what is supposed to happen? I am very confused now.

Comment: btw it still isn't loading in IE but now the datepicker is not functioning at all when clicked.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code just a bit a go. It needed to get wrapped in a function literal: `onSelect: function(){setTimeout(dateChanged, 500);}`. That *should* prevent it from executing immediately.

Comment: alright that makes sense. I am still at a loss. For whatever reason I am still not getting the function to fire past the variable declarations. It seems to be getting to dateChanged() but as soon as it tries to call the line 'var StartTime = startDate.value;` it stops. I have before tried to put something else there such as the `var cmecProx2 = new cmec();` and it fails to load that as well. I do appreciate your help though so if you have any more suggestions I would be most appreciative.

Comment: I found some problems. For some reason I cannot retrieve the inputs values such as startDate.value or endDate.value. If I hard code values in for them instead it works fine.

Comment: Is IE reporting any errors to you? It sounds like there is an error in there somewhere that only IE cares about. It seems `startDate` and `endDate` are getting set outside of the `dateChanged()` function. How are they being set? Are you sure they exist and that they contain the objects you expect?

Comment: Then it sounds like you'll need to use `$('startDate').val()` and `$('endDate').val()` to retrieve those values.

Comment: I had a similar thought. I will apply that and post back with my findings. Thank you for all your help. You have been most helpful.